# Hyperledger channel creation on orderer Error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am getting an error while creating the channel on orderer (up and running). I have created the crypto artifacts as well as channel artifacts but while creating the channel. I am getting the error given below. I have file created ch1.tx at specified location but still getting the issue:

> Error: channel create configuration tx file not found open /etc/hyperledger/fabric/ch1.tx: no such file or directory

My .YAML file  looks like:

```
version: '2'

networks:
  rpnw:

services:
  peer0:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.4
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org0MSP"
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=false
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/usr/local/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org0/peers/peer0.org0/tls/ca.crt
      #- CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/root/bcnetwork/conf/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org0/users/Admin@org0/msp 
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=org0-peer0:7051  #peer0  peer_peer-base_1

    working_dir: /usr/local/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer channel create -o orderer0:7050 -c ch1 -f /etc/hyperledger/fabric/ch1.tx  # peer_orderer0_1
    networks:
      - rpnw
```

Please help.

Comment: "I have file created ch1.tx" ---

did you make sure to copy this file inside the container?

Comment: How do i copy the file inside the container ?

Comment: I do not think you need to copy file inside container, instead you can just mount a volume with folder which contains your files.

Comment: Thanks . It works.